# How to dynamically create multiple TcpOutboundGateways using Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I have a scenario where I need a single client application to be able to dynamically create TCP connections to a variable number of unique host/port combinations at application startup. I am trying to accomplish this using the Spring Integration TcpOutboundGateway but have been unable to find a solution. I want each of the host/port combinations to have its own dedicated TcpOutboundGateway. My research of the TcpOutboundGateway up to this point has led me to the following, single gateway, solution…

```
@MessageGateway(defaultRequestChannel=“sendMessage”)
public interface myMessageGateway {
    byte[] sendMessage(String message);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel=“sendMessage”)
public MessageHandler tcpOutboundGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory factory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway gateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    return gateway;
}

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
    return new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(“123.456.789.0”, 5555);
}
```

Where my understanding is that calling the sendMessage function will put the request message on the “sendMessage” channel. That channel will then pass it to the tcpOutboundGateway service activator which will handle the sending of the message and ultimately return the server's response as the return of the sendMessage function. This solution has worked fine for me in scenarios of a singular, predefined server connection.

My question is how can I dynamically create new Message Gateways and Service Activators in a way that can support a variable set of unique host/ports? More specifically, what is the @MessageGateway and @ServiceActivator annotations doing for us in the background and what do I need to do in order to replicate that functionality?

**EDIT:**

So after some experimenting I landed on this solution which seems to do the trick...

```
// Define the Message Gateway without any annotations
public interface MyMessageGateway {
    byte[] sendMessage(String message);
}

...

// Use the GatewayProxyFactoryBean to replicate the functionality of the @MessageGateway annotation
// context is my instance of a ConfigurableApplicationContext
GatewayProxyFactoryBean gpfb = new GatewayProxyFactoryBean(SenderGateway.class);
gpfb.setDefaultRequestChannel(“sendMessage”);
context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(“MyMessageGateway”, gpfb);
context.getBeanFactory().initializeBean(gpfb, “MyMessageGateway”);

// Create and register the ClientConnectionFactory Bean within the Application Context
AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(“123.456.789.0”, 5000);
context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(“ClientConnectionFactory”, clientConnectionFactory);
context.getBeanFactory().initializeBean(clientConnectionFactory, “ClientConnectionFactory”);

// Create and register the TcpOutboundGateway Bean within the Application Context
TcpOutboundGateway gateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
gateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(“TcpOutboundGateway”, tcpOutboundGateway);
context.getBeanFactory().initializeBean(tcpOutboundGateway, “TcpOutboundGateway”);

// Create and register the Request Channel to connect the Message Gateway and the TCP Outbound Gateway
// This should replicate the functionality of the @ServiceActivator annotation
DirectChannel sendMessage = new DirectChannel();
sendMessage.setBeanName(“sendMessage”);
context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(“sendMessage”, sendMessage);
context.getBeanFactory().initializeBean(sendMessage, “sendMessage”);

// Subscribe the TCP Outbound Gateway to the new Message Channel (sendMessage)
// This should replicate the functionality of the @ServiceActivator annotation
sendMessage.subscribe(tcpOutboundGateway);

// Start the ClientConnectionFactory
// This seems to be getting done automatically in the non-dynamic implementation above
clientConnectionFactory.start();
```

This implementation allows for messages to be sent via the Message Gateway and TCP Outbound Gateway in the same manner as the annotated implementation above (using the sendMessage function defined for the MyMessageGateway interface). I have found that in order to use this approach for more then one host/port combination you will need to get the desired Message Gateway via the context.getBeanFactory.getBean().

I am curious if there are any flaws in this approach/implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The only simple way to do that is to consider to use a dynamic `IntegrationFlow`s with Java DSL provided by Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#java-dsl-runtime-flows

We also have a comprehensive sample exactly for similar *dynamic TCP client*  use-case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client

Comment: Artem, could you elaborate on your provided solutions? I am new to IntegrationFlow and can’t fully understand how you envision this being used for my scenario. Maybe an example/pseudocode if possible? I also notice the first example is using the function convertAndSend which makes it seem that there is no need for anything similar to the @MessageGateway interface in my example above. Is that a correct assumption? Once we have created and registered the IntegrationFlow for each host/port combination how would I reference it? Would it become a bean in the ApplicationContext?

Comment: Artem - please also see my edit to the original question. Think I found a possible solution.

Comment: You did yourself something similar what we do in the framework behind that `IntegrationFlowContext`. You still can use a `@MessagingGateway` to send message for the particular host/port and select an appropriate `IntegrationFlow` for interaction from some simple cache. I think our mention sample has enough information to borrow for your request/reply solution. Although if you are happy with your own one, that's OK, too: we had something similar in the beginning as well.